# Describe the set of points where $f(x,y) = x^{y}$ is less than 1

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Only consider points in the domain, where x > 0.

I'm not quite sure how to solve this problem. I have sketched the level curves and am wondering if it has something to do with that?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Think about the definition of $x^y$, it could help you, didn't it ?

Comment: things change when $x$ crosses $1$ or when $y$ crosses $0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to approach these types of problems is to first find the boundaries.

We have $$x^y=1\implies y\log x=0$$

Hence the boundary is defined by the lines $y=0$ and $x=1$ (and don't forget we also have $x>0$).
This gives you $4$ regions to check, and you can test each region simply by plugging in a point of the region to see if it satisfies the inequality.